# Solving a simple trigonometric equation for coefficients

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Is it possible to solve the equation

$$ a \sin x + b \cos x + c \cos^3 x = d \cos x $$

where $c\neq0$ using some coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$? I can't see how to make the frequency of oscillation for the left hand side of the equation equal to the frequency for the right hand side.

Comment: $c=0$ (otherwise you have oscillation with triple frequency on the left side), then $a=0$ (for $x=\pi / 2$) and $b=d$. Why did you think other solutions exist?

Comment: So your question actually is whether such $p,q$ so that $\cos^3x=p\cos x + q \sin x$ exist?

Comment: Are you trying to make it true for all $x$ (you can't ) or find an $x$ that works for given. $a,b,c,d?$ Note that $b$ and $d$ are redundant.

Answer (score 1):

(Pursuant to Mr. Millikan's observation that $b$ and $d$ can be combined, I now replace the both of them with $e$.) So, $a\sin{x}+e\cos{x}+c\cos^3{x}=0$.

How about moving $a\sin{x}$ to the RHS, then squaring, then substituting $a^2-a^2\cos^2{x}$ for $a^2\sin^2{x}$? This would give you a cubic equation in $\cos^2{x}$. No guarantee, though, that $\cos^2{x}$ would turn out to be a proper value for a squared cosine -- i.e., $\in [0,1]$. It all depends upon the coëfficients.
$=================================$
$$c^2\cos^6{x}+2ce\cos^4{x}+(e^2+a^2)\cos^2{x}-a^2=0$$